# Finding an equation when given a limit

Tags: limits

I have a math homework that I have no clue how to complete. It’s asking me to graph a line when it gives me the limit and I need to find the equation because I need to program the graph.

F(x) is continuous everywhere
Lim x-> inf f(x) =5
Lim x-> -inf f(x) = infinity

Answer (score 0):

You can take
$$f(x)=5+e^{-x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}=5+0=5$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}=5+\infty=+\infty$$

$f$ is continuous at $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ok, but how did you figure that out?